# Cannot find cert: drive or Certificate Provider via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, certificate, powershell-5.0

For some reason, it seems that my install of Windows 10/Powershell 5.0 is missing the [Certificate Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/providers/certificate-provider?view=powershell-6).  It seems like I somehow don't even have the [Microsoft.PowerShell.Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847877.aspx) module that is supposed to be installed with powershell by default and includes the certificate provider.  Here is what I get when I run Get-Module (I added post-git sometime ago, maybe I messed it up when I did that?):

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     0.7.1      posh-git                            {Add-PoshGitToProfile, Add-SshKey, Enable-GitColors, Get-A...
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...
```

and here is what I get when I run Get-PSProvider:

```
Name                 Capabilities                                      Drives
----                 ------------                                      ------
Registry             ShouldProcess, Transactions                       {HKLM, HKCU}
Alias                ShouldProcess                                     {Alias}
Environment          ShouldProcess                                     {Env}
FileSystem           Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials                {C, D, E}
Function             ShouldProcess                                     {Function}
Variable             ShouldProcess                                     {Variable}
```

Is there anyway that I can reinstall PowerShell or add this provider/drive to my build without reinstalling Windows entirely?  Something very fishy seems to have happened to my machine and I'd really rather not do a full reinstall if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I get the same modules and providers as you, that's normal, what do you get is you do a `ls cert:`?

Comment: and this: `Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Certificate | fl *` ?

Comment: `Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Certificate | fl *
    Get-PSProvider : Cannot find a provider with the name 'Certificate'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Get-PSProvider -PSProvider Certificate | fl *
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Certificate:String) [Get-PSProvider], ProviderNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetPSProviderCommand`

Comment: `ls cert:
ls : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'cert' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls cert:
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cert:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: That is indeed fishy, never seen that. Do you have `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.psd1` and `C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_microsoft.powershell.security_*` files?

Comment: I do have both of those (5 different directories that match the second row that you mentioned).  Yea, this is really weird and doesn't make sense to me, and I couldn't find any other question that really seemed to reference this issue either.

Comment: Also, I tried to install/import PSPKI[https://github.com/Crypt32/PSPKI] which works but doesn't seem to help in my particular case unless there is some additional setup I need to do with that.  Not sure if that is helpful at all, was one of the things I found when searching for the answer.

Comment: You should be able to run a restore on your Windows installation to fix the issue.

Comment: I am running in to the same problem. I have a new windows installation so a restore is not an option. Any other ideas or thought in to why this could be happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error when running a custom powershell action during an MSI install.  Maco1717's answer pointed me in the right direction.  Turns out the PSModulePath was different when Powershell was running in Installer context.  The fix was to load the proper paths from environment variables like this, at the beginning of the script:

```
$env:PSModulePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, though I don't exactly know why `PSModulePath` is being messed up!

Answer (score 2):

I came to find the same issue.

I my case the problem was the PSModulePath environment variable did not have the right paths in it.

Comment: What paths does it need? Where is the provider located?

Comment: @DarenThomas For certificates it will be PKI module. Your best bet is to read the module paths from environment variable, and copy into session module path variable like this: $env:PSModulePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine')

Answer (score 1):

Another very special case appears to be when using PowerShell 5.1 which ends up loading the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` module from PowerShell 7.0.

In normal circumstances `$env:PSModulePath` should not contain the path to the PS7 modules, but it did for me. I do not fully understand why yet, has something to do with a custom host application for PowerShell.

So this is what happened for me:

```bash
> Import-Module pki
> Get-Module | Select-Object -Property Name,Path

Name                            Path
----                            ----
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.Powe...
pki                             C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\pki\pki.psd1
```

This is mixing PS7 with PS5.1 modules, which is not good. I ended up manually patching `$env:PSModulePath`, removing the PS7 module path. After that, running the same code again and it worked fine:

```bash
Name                            Path
----                            ----
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\M...
pki                             C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\pki\pki.psd1
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem! In my case though, the PSModule environmental variable looks fine. I can run list `Cert:`  both in Powershel 5 and 7 through the regular `CLI` interface. But if I call it via `Process` in any code `Python`/`Dart`, etc it only works if I call `pwsh.exe` but not with `powershell.exe`.